# PGFPlots PDF printing issue (Adobe Reader DC)

Tags: pgfplots, pdf, adobe

Here is my source code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pgfplotsset{samples=1000}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center,
            height=70mm,
            width=70mm,
            ytick=\empty,       
            xtick=\empty,
            ymin=-25,
            ymax=25,
            xmin=-25,
            xmax=25
        ]
        \addplot[line width=0.2mm, mark=none, domain=-25:25] {0.00025*(x^5-12*x^4)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}        
\end{document}
```

Compiled PDF looks like this in Adobe Reader:

[image: Plot]

But if I print it out the result looks like this (additional lines are added):

[image: Print]

I'm using Adobe Reader DC 15.010.20060 and PGFPlots 1.12.1.

Comment: can you add `compat=1.12` or better upgrade to 1.13? This is a duplicate if I remember correctly

Comment: @percusse compat=1.12 and update to 1.13 doesn't help, domain=-15:15 does.

Comment: @Roald It's not a solution just a workaround.

Comment: But still solved your problem. Maybe not _the_ answer, _an_ answer.

Comment: @Roald Not really _solved_: I've got several graphs like this and instead of just using `\clip[]` I have to adjust all the domains manually.